# Is there a robust way to align the baseline of subscripts?

Tags: math-mode, equations, subscripts

A minimal example of my issue is
`T_a T_b` vs `T_a T_{\dot b}`.

In the second, I want the `b` subscript to align with the `a` subscript irrespective of the overset. I know there probably hacky ways to create negative space on the second subscript, but I want something that can scale with the math.

Maybe something along the lines of making the box of `\dot b` the same size as just a regular `b` somehow?

EDIT: MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$T_a T_b$ vs $T_a T_{\dot b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome into the site TeX.SE.

Comment: Could you add a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: One could do something like `T\strut_a T\strut_{\dot b}` which aligns the subscripts but moves them to an unnaturally low location.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common approach here is to use a `\vphantom` of the larger object, or `\smash` the larger next to a `\vphantom` of the smaller:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$T_a T_b$ vs 
  $T_a T_{\dot{b}}$ vs
  $T_{\vphantom{\dot{b}}a} T_{\dot{b}}$ vs
  $T_a T_{\vphantom{a}\smash{\dot{b}}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, `\smash` is probably all I need here.

Answer (score 7):

Borrowing from Hendrik's answer here: [Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript without breaking file names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript-without-breaking-file-names)

NOT recommended!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \gdef_#1{\ensuremath{\sb{\smash{#1}}}}
\endgroup
\mathcode`\_=\string"8000
\catcode`\_=12

\begin{document}
$T_a T_b$ vs $T_a T_{\dot b}.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the subscripts universally lower, a variation of the suggestion of NoWayHaze would be this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \gdef_#1{\ensuremath{\sb{\strut#1}}}
\endgroup
\mathcode`\_=\string"8000
\catcode`\_=12

\begin{document}
$T_a T_b$ vs $T_a T_{\dot b}.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As an alternative, you could sacrifice another character, here a `!`, to specifically mean a subscript in which the height of the element is ignored.  Then, you can still use `_` in the normal cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \catcode`\!=\active
  \gdef!#1{\ensuremath{\sb{\smash{#1}}}}
\endgroup
\mathcode`\!=\string"8000
\catcode`\!=12

\begin{document}
$T_a T_{\dot b}.$ vs $T_a T!{\dot b}.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Then can I not vote your answer? :)

Comment: @Sebastiano With my edit, I feel more comfortable allowing you to upvote  `;^)`

Comment: I have done before (the upvote)...excuse me very very much :-)

Comment: I feel like the alternative answer this probably is good enough for my uses for now. Luckily, as far as I can tell, this issue doesn't affect superscripts.

Comment: +1! it is very close what i imagine to be solution to my question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297754/positions-of-variable-indices-use-of-package-subdepth